# Where can I find Maghda?

Tags: diablo-iii

Does anybody know how to kill Maghda in the first chapter of season 17? It says kill Maghda, but apparantly I can't find the character anywhere and because of this I can't move on to chapter two.

Where do I find Maghda and how do I kill her?

Comment: Maghda is already in act 2 and not in act 1

Answer (score 12):

I think you've mixed up the seasonal chapters and the in-game acts.

Maghda is a boss you have to defeat in order to progress the seasonal journey (chapter). But she's an **act two** boss.

You will find her by teleporting to the **"Road to Alcarnus" waypoint**. After that head east first, go up the stairs at the end of town and then head north. She will be waiting in the next area.

To get to act two just zoom out the world map in adventure mode. If you haven't unlocked adventure mode yet you will encounter her if you just progress through the story normally.

Answer (score -1):

The first 4 chapters of the season journey are supposed to "guide" you through the game and will be picked up almost naturally as you proceed through the story.

They will be an additional incentive to try out things that are not obligatory such as socketing equipment or enchanting weapons.

Until the 4th chapter, there will be no boss that you do not pass naturally through the storyline. The only thing worth noting is the difficulty at which you need to defeat the boss.